# Level Order Traversal of a tree

Tags: java, algorithm, generics, tree, tree-traversal

In order to do level order(BFS) traversal of a generic tree I wrote the following display function for the code  mentioned in the link below. The problem is that each level is printed twice. Can someone tell me why.
Original Code without this function can be found in the link below in case someone need the entire implementation else just look at the  displayBFS function below and tell me why are values repeating

[Level Order traversal of a generic tree(n-ary tree) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788641/level-order-traversal-of-a-generic-treen-ary-tree-in-java)

Thanks!

```
void displayBFS(NaryTreeNode n)
{
    Queue<NaryTreeNode> q  = new LinkedList<NaryTreeNode>();

    if(n!=null)
    {
        q.add(n);
        System.out.println(n.data);
    }

    while(n!=null)
    {
        for(NaryTreeNode x:n.nary_list)
        {
            q.add(x);
            System.out.println(x.data );
        }        
        n =  q.poll();
    }  
}
```

Current Tree Structure for reference:

```
     root(100)
    /      |       \
  90       50       70
  /        \
20 30   200  300
```

Output:
    100
    90 
    50
    70
    90
    50
    70 
    20
    30
    200
    300
    20
    30
    200
    300

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you process your root-node twice: you initially add it to your queue (in the line `q.add(n)`), then you process it *before* you first get to `n = q.poll()`, and then you get it off the queue and process it again.

Everything else is correct, which is why you only get two copies of each non-root node: the doubling only occurs once, at root.

To fix this, either remove the line `q.add(n)` (since you process the root node anyway, even without it), or else change this:

```
    while(n!=null)
    {
        ...
        n =  q.poll();
    }
```

to this:

```
    while((n = q.poll()) != null)
    {
        ...
    }
```

so that you don't process the root node that initial extra time.