# Level Order tree Traversal for a generic tree, displaying the tree level by level

Tags: java, algorithm, tree, tree-traversal, directed-acyclic-graphs

I would like to display the tree structure level by level. My current code does a BFS or Level Order Traversal but I cannot get the output to display the tree structure like a tree
See current output and Expected output.

My idea was to use some kind of count to iterate over elements from the same level in the queue.

How can I do so.

Original Code without this function can be found in the link below in case someone needs the entire implementation else just look at the  displayBFS function below.

[Level Order traversal of a generic tree(n-ary tree) in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12788641/level-order-traversal-of-a-generic-treen-ary-tree-in-java)

Thanks!

```
   void displayBFS(NaryTreeNode n)
   {
      Queue<NaryTreeNode> q  = new LinkedList<NaryTreeNode>();
      System.out.println(n.data);

       while(n!=null)
     {   
         for(NaryTreeNode x:n.nary_list)
         {
             q.add(x);
             System.out.print(x.data + " ");
         }
         n=q.poll();
         System.out.println();
      } 
  }

Current Tree Structure for reference:

         root(100)
        /      |       \
      90       50       70
      /        \
    20 30   200  300


    Current Output:
        100
        90 50 70
        20 30
        200 300

    Expected Output
        100
        90 50 70
        20 30 200 300
```

Also, I had posted a logic issue with the same function earlier, as that was answered and the current question realtes to a different problem, I posted a new question, is this approach okay or should I make edits to the earlier question and not open a new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

only need to keep track of current level and next level.

```
static void displayBFS(NaryTreeNode root) {
    int curlevel = 1;
    int nextlevel = 0;

    LinkedList<NaryTreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<NaryTreeNode>();
    queue.add(root);

    while(!queue.isEmpty()) { 
        NaryTreeNode node = queue.remove(0);

        if (curlevel == 0) {
            System.out.println();
            curlevel = nextlevel;
            nextlevel = 0;
        }

        for(NaryTreeNode n : node.nary_list) {
            queue.addLast(n);
            nextlevel++;
        }

        curlevel--;
        System.out.print(node.data + " ");
    } 
}
```

when you switch levels, swap nextlevel for currentlevel and reset nextlevel. i prefer the simplicity of this over keeping a whole separate queue.

i had this question for a microsoft interview last week... it didn't go so well for me over the phone. good on you for studying it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution I know of to this problem is to use a sentinel. The queue is initialized with the root node followed by the sentinel, and then you loop through the queue:

1. remove the front element
2. if it is the sentinel:

   - we're at the end of a level, so we can end the output line
   - if the queue is not empty, push the sentinel back onto the queue at the end.
3. if it is not the sentinel:

   - print it out
   - push all its children onto the queue.

I don't do Java, but I have some C++ code for depth-aware BFS, which I stripped down to do this printing task:

```
void show_tree_by_levels(std::ostream& os, Node* tree) {
  Node* sentinel = new Node;
  std::deque<Node*> queue{tree, sentinel};
  while (true) {
    Node* here = queue.front();
    queue.pop_front();
    if (here == sentinel) {
      os << std::endl;
      if (queue.empty())
        break;
      else
        queue.push_back(sentinel);
    } else {
      for (Node* child = here->child; child; child = child->sibling)
        queue.push_back(child);
      os << here->value << ' ';
    }
  }
}
```

Note that I prefer to use a two-pointer solution (first_child/next_sibling), because it usually works out to be simpler than embedded lists. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Use another queue to indicate depth.
The below code is not tested, but it should give you the idea (the sep variable is introduced to avoid trailing white-spaces):

```
void displayBFS(NaryTreeNode n) {
  Queue<NaryTreeNode> q  = new LinkedList<NaryTreeNode>();
  Queue<Integer> depth  = new LinkedList<Integer>();
  q.add(n);
  depth.add(0);

  String sep = "";
  int oldDepth = 0

  while(!q.isEmpty()) {
    NaryTreeNode currN = q.poll();
    int currDepth = depth.poll();
    if (currDepth > oldDepth) {
      System.out.println();
      oldDepth = currDepth;
      sep = "";
    }
    System.out.print(sep + currN.data);
    sep = " ";

    for(NaryTreeNode x : currN.nary_list) {
      q.add(x);
      depth.add(currDepth + 1);
    }
  }
}
```

For my taste this approach is more self-explanatory compared to other ways one could do it.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need three more variables. *numInCurrentLevel* for keeping track of the number of elements in current level, *indexInCurrentLevel* for doing the count when traversal in current level and *numInNextLevel* for keeping track of the number of elements in next level. The code is below:

```
static void displayBFS(NaryTreeNode root) {

    Queue<NaryTreeNode> q  = new LinkedList<NaryTreeNode>();;
    q.add(root);
    int numInCurrentLevel = 1;
    int numInNextLevel = 0;
    int indexInCurrentLevel=0;

    while(!q.isEmpty()) { 
        NaryTreeNode node = q.poll();
        System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        indexInCurrentLevel++;

        for(NaryTreeNode n : node.nary_list) {
            q.add(n);
            numInNextLevel++;
        }

        //finish traversal in current level
        if(indexInCurrentLevel==numInCurrentLevel) {
            System.out.println();
            numInCurrentLevel=numInNextLevel;
            numInNextLevel=0;           
            indexInCurrentLevel=0;
        }
  } 
}
```

Hope it helps, I am not so familiar with java programming.

Answer (score 0):

```
def printLevelWiseTree(tree):
q= queue.Queue()
if tree == None:
    return None
q.put(tree)
while (not(q.empty())):
    c = q.get()
    print(c.data,end=":")
    for i in range(len(c.children)):
        if i != len(c.children)-1:
            print(c.children[i].data,end=",")
        else:
            print(c.children[i].data,end="")
        q.put(c.children[i])
    print()
```